# integration of multiple place autocomplete address form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to add the [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) couples times in my view as a partial view:

**Partial view _GeoApi**

```
 @model int

  <p><input type="text" onfocus="geolocate(@Model)" placeholder="Taper l'adresse"  id="@("autocomplete" + Model)" class=" fiche" name="nomlieu_adress" style="width:500px"></p>

    <p>
        <label style="width:90px">Avenue</label><input type="text" class=" fiche" id="@("street_number"+Model)" name="avenue_adress" style="width:160px; " />
        <label style="width:90px">Rue</label><input type="text" class=" fiche"   id="@("route" + Model)" name="rue_adress" style="width:157px" />
    </p>

    <p> <label style="width:90px">Ville(*)</label><input type="text" class=" fiche"   id="@("locality" + Model)" name="ville_adress" style="width:410px" required /> </p>

    <p>
        <label style="width:90px">Etat(*)</label><input type="text"   id="@("administrative_area_level_1" + Model)" class=" fiche" name="etat_adress" style="width:160px" required />
        <label style="width:90px">Code Postal(*)</label><input type="text"   id="@("postal_code" + Model)" class=" fiche" name="code_postal_adress" style="width:157px" required />
    </p>

    <p> <label style="width:90px">Pays(*)</label><input type="text"   id="@("country" + Model)" class=" fiche" name="pays_adress" style="width:410px" required /></p>
```

**Main view**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DemandeClient/AjouterDemande.js"></script>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1">
    <form class="editForm">

      @Html.Partial("_GeoApi",1)

    </form>
</div>
..............................
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
    <form class="editForm">

      @Html.Partial("_GeoApi",2)

    </form>
</div>
..................................
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
    <form class="editForm">

      @Html.Partial("_GeoApi",3)

    </form>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete1, autocomplete2, autocomplete3;
var componentForm1 = {
    street_number1: 'short_name',
    route1: 'long_name',
    locality1: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_11: 'short_name',
    country1: 'long_name',
    postal_code1: 'short_name'
};

var componentForm2 = {
    street_number2: 'short_name',
    route2: 'long_name',
    locality2: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
    country2: 'long_name',
    postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

var componentForm3 = {
    street_number3: 'short_name',
    route3: 'long_name',
    locality3: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_13: 'short_name',
    country3: 'long_name',
    postal_code3: 'short_name'
};

    function initAutocomplete() {

        console.log("initAutocomplete");

        try {
            autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete1')), { types: ['geocode'] });
            autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(1));

            autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), { types: ['geocode'] });
            autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(2));

            autocomplete3 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete3')), { types: ['geocode'] });
            autocomplete3.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(3));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("exception from initAutocomplete = " + e.message);
        }



    }


    function fillInAddress(numb) {

        console.log("fillInAddress (" + numb + ")");

        try {

        if (numb == 1)
        {
             var place = autocomplete1.getPlace(); 
             for (var component in componentForm1) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm1[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm1[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

            if (numb == 2)
            {
                var place  = autocomplete2.getPlace(); 
                for (var component in componentForm2) {
                    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                    if (componentForm2[addressType]) {
                        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType]];
                        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                    }
                }
            }

                if (numb == 3)
                {
                    var place = autocomplete3.getPlace(); 
                    for (var component in componentForm3) {
                        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                        if (componentForm3[addressType]) {
                            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm3[addressType]];
                            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                        }
                    }
                }


        } catch (e) {
            console.log("exception from fillInAddress (" + numb + ") = " + e.message);
        }

    }



    function geolocate(numb) {

        console.log("geolocate (" + numb + ")");

        try {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });

                    if (numb == 1) autocomplete1.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                    if (numb == 2) autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                    if (numb == 3) autocomplete3.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("exception from geolocate (" + numb + ") = " + e.message);
        }

    }
```

when I run the application I get these errors in the loading

> > initAutocomplete
>
> fillInAddress (1)
>
> exception from fillInAddress (1) = Cannot read property
>   'address_components' of undefined
>
> fillInAddress (2)
>
> exception from fillInAddress (2) = Cannot read property
>   'address_components' of undefined
>
> fillInAddress (3)
>
> exception from fillInAddress (3) = Cannot read property
>   'address_components' of undefined

when I focus in for example the first autocomplete form, I get the message `geolocate (1)` but when I select a place this exception appear:

> js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:104
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of
>   undefined_.J.trigger @
>   js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:104sb
>   @
>   js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:38sb
>   @
>   js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:38_.t.set
>   @
>   js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:106(anonymous
>   function) @
>   js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:52(anonymous
>   function) @ places_impl.js:24(anonymous function) @
>   places_impl.js:14(anonymous function) @ places_impl.js:8(anonymous
>   function) @ common.js:43(anonymous function) @ common.js:34(anonymous
>   function) @ common.js:43d @ common.js:39(anonymous function) @
>   PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?2sfr-FR&8sChIJ0XsDKGqKfg0RovjXq-O-QHE&10e3&key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx…:1

So I need to know:

1. What are the reasons of these exceptions?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are your autocompleteX variables defined globally anywhere?

Comment: @Mufaka yeah, please see my edit code( script part)